# void* in variadic functions

Tags: objective-c, void-pointers, variadic-functions

I am trying to create a method that accepts an arbitrary number of arguments that will be used to create an NSInvocation (an object wrapper around a method). Can void pointers be passed as arguments in a variadic function or does the compiler need to know the size of the type being passed ahead of time? NSInvocation instance method "setArgument:(void*) atIndex:index" is normally how this is done.

```
-(void)addArguments:(void *)argument, ... {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, argument);

    int index = 2;
    void *value;
    [self.invocation setArgument:argument atIndex:index];
    index++;

    while ((value = va_arg(args, void*)))
    {
        [self.invocation setArgument:value atIndex:index];
        index++;
    }
    va_end(args);
    return;
}
```

Comment: As far as the compiler's concerned, you just get a reference to some memory chunk.  It doesn't need to know the size of a pointer type, just the pointer.  NSInvocation uses void* so it can accept parameters that aren't necessarily objects, especially primitives, which are usually just passed by taking the address of them.  &5 is a perfectly valid parameter just as an NSObject* descendant is.

Comment: Great, thank you. The reason I was unsure is because while I could find very little online about this subject specifically, this author (http://www.enigmaticape.com/blog/wrapping-nsinvocation-for-fun-and-profit/) says it can't be done. "Unfortunately for our purposes, this requires to you to know the type of each argument in advance, which means we can't use it in a suitably generic way..." All the other examples I looked at were also using very roundabout techniques to accomplish it. Are those people just bad programmers?.

Comment: He's not a "bad programmer", he's dealing with the personal hell that is unpacking an NSValue generically.

Comment: But why is he wrapping basic types in an NSValue, if they can be passed by address instead?

Comment: Because he wants to pass around things that aren't objects or simple data types (like structs, CGPoints, CGRects, etc.). Unless your use-case calls for you to have to accept those types, void* will suffice. Depending on the situation, I'd go even further and make it so that only object types (id) can be passed.

Comment: Right now I'm using it to pass simple types, structs, and objects. Haven't run into any problems yet, but wanted to make sure I wasn't missing any nasty memory bug. Is there a reason structs can't be passed in this same way, as long as the struct's address is passed? Thanks for your help. I'd prefer not to use only objects, since it's deeply tied to existing code that would have to be changed.

Comment: You can pass a pointer to a struct just fine.  There is absolutely no reason to explicitly wrap anything in an NSValue.